# How does one find out whether $N = a^b$ for some integer $a$ and $b$?

Tags: algorithms, decision-problem, diophantine-equation

I was trying to find out how to find whether $N$ is a perfect power or not for some $a$ and $b$ (so the algorithm should discover that it is not a perfect power if it is not expressible in the form $a^b$).

My intuition tells me that for every value of the exponent $b$ we can binary search $a$ in the set $\{ 1,...,N-1 \}$. However, what I am not convinced yet is that this algorithm won't run forever, i.e. that we won't try new values of $b$ forever. Are there efficient algorithms?

Comment: How about finding the prime factorisation as a first step?

Comment: found: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-power-in-polynomial-time

Comment: (`finding the prime factorisation` seems to be slow intolerably slow, as [detecting perfect powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power#Detecting_perfect_powers) is a first step in a [fast primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Algorithm). That said, I have no idea about the operations considered to take unit time in algorithms using transcendental functions.)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/26379/755

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your approach is a good one.  The only thing you missed is that there's a simple upper bound $b \le \lg N$.

Do you see why?  It's easier to see why if you state more carefully the problem  you are trying to solve.  You are asking whether there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \ge 2$, $b \ge 2$, and $a^b=N$.  Taking logs of both sides, we get $b \lg a = \lg N$.  From the fact that $a \ge 2$, we see $\lg a \ge 1$, so $b = (\lg N)/(\lg a) \le \lg N$.

Therefore, here is a simple algorithm:

- For $b=2,3,\dots,\lg N$:

  - Use binary search to search for $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^b=N$.

Each iteration of the loop will take $O(\lg N)$ time (the time for a binary search over at most $N$ possibilities), and you do $\lg N$ iterations of the loop, so the total running time $O((\lg N)^2)$.

In particular, yes, this will always terminate.  You don't need to keep trying new values for $b$ forever, since we know that $b$ is an integer and is no larger than $\lg N$.

The running time of the algorithm can be improved a bit by replacing the binary search with a faster algorithm to compute $\sqrt[b]{N}$; for instance, you could use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).  But the basic method above is already very efficient.

---

You might be tempted to iterate over all possible values of $a$, and then do a binary search for $b$.  Don't do that; there are $\Theta(\sqrt{N})$ possible values of $a$, so this will be unavoidably slow.

Instead, a better approach is to iterate over all possible values of $b$, and then do a binary search for a matching $a$.  This is much faster, as it needs only $\Theta(\lg N)$ binary searches rather than $\Theta(\sqrt{N})$ of them.

One person mentioned factoring $N$.  This is much slower.  Our best algorithms for factoring run in subexponential time; they are much slower than the $\Theta((\lg N)^2)$ running time of the algorithm above.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @templatetypedef described, assuming we are talking about natural numbers, $a > 1$, and $b > 1$ we can make the following considerations:

- The greatest number $a$ we have to consider is $sqrt(N)$, being that $sqrt(N)^2 = N$, so $a <= sqrt(N)$.
- From the numbers we got in the previous point we can consider only half of them; even numbers if $N mod 2 = 0$, odd if $N mod 2 = 1$
- The bigger $a$ is, the smaller $b$.

So, summing it up, you can follow the algorithm suggested by @templatetypedef while keeping in mind the lower/upper limits of $a$ and $b$, and avoiding odd/even numbers depending on $N$. If you need the greates $a$ possible you just start with the greatest $a$ such that $a <= sqrt(N)$. If you need the smallest you can start with $a = 2$.

Comment: This is not a good approach.  It is far, far slower: its running time is $\Theta(N^{1/2})$, which is exoonentially slower than the strategy listed in the question.  See my answer: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48060/755

Comment: You're right actually. The linear approach is not so efficient. Nevertheless, by using the considerations on the possible values of $a$ given in here with your consideration on the possible values of $b$ and the binary search on the possible values of $a$ it should be a bit faster, even though in terms of complexity it remains $O((lg N)^2)$.