# Can we decide if a number is a power of any given $K$ in polynomial-time?

Tags: algorithms, polynomial-time

It is simple to decide powers of 2 in $O(n)$ time because it's just *"0-bit Unary"* after *bit-1*. (eg. $1000$ is a *power of 2* in binary).

I haven't found many other trivial *powers of* $K$ that can be decided in polynomial-time with the binary-length of the input.

### Question

Can we decide if a number is a power of any given $K$ in polynomial-time and in a practical amount of time?

Something not naive such as keep dividing $N$ by $K$ until you reach the smallest value $2$ for deciding a power of 2.

Comment: This also allows a special case of factorization in $P$. Just simply delete the 0-bit one by one at a time until you reach $1$. Each iteration is a factor of a power of $2$. Use binary factors, not integer factors. Integer factors would be slower!

Comment: Yes. Use binary search on the value of the exponent. See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48033/755.

Comment: @D.W. Seems like a $O(n log n)$ algorithm (integer factorization of powers of 2). If I could guess, I'm just an amateur tinkering in college algebra and lots of python practice.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You are given a number `N` and number `K` and want to check whether `N` is a power of `K`? Why no just divide `N` by `K` repeatedly? It will be polynomial in the length of `N`.

Comment: @Dmitry Seems impractical when I have $2$^$1000000000.....$. I could just check there is all zero bits. I want practical and polynomial.

Comment: Well, then you should write this in you question. And try to specify what practical means

Comment: @TravisWells "I could just check there is all zero bits". You are assuming that the input is encoded in binary. This assumption doesn't have to be the case, so you should make it explicit in the question. If that assumption is made, what you are saying is the same as dividing by $2$ repeatedly.

Comment: Instead of dividing by $K$ each time, I would compute $K, K^2, K^{2^2},K^{2^3},...$ and divide by the largest such that is not larger than $N$. Repeat the same procedure with the resulting quotient. It would take about $\log_2(\log_K(N))$ divisions, same number of multiplications (squaring). Then you can count each of these big int operations how fast they are in bit operations.

Comment: Are you asking whether $N$ is a perfect power? If $K$ is fixed, using logaritms gives a pretty good idea of the power (don't need high precision!) and a few trials to check.